# Mathematical expression from string

Tags: php, math, evaluation

Can someone please tell if I can in PHP evaluate math expression to number?
For example I have expresssion: **(20 + 40%) + 20%** I would get **33.6**

I tried using EvalMath class from here: https://www.phpclasses.org/package/2695-PHP-Safely-evaluate-mathematical-expressions.html but it doesn't do the trick

Comment: use simple mathematics.. 40% into 0.4 (40/100)

Comment: [PHP doc](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.math.php) says that

Comment: Do you really want EvalMath or simple math can do it ? `$a =20; $b = $a+ ((40/100)*$a); $c = $b+ (20/100)*$b; print $c;` I let you boil down this expression to a more simple one. I'm sure you can do it.

Answer (score 0):

Thats just simple math.

If you have an expression `$x + $y%` - thats the same as `$x + (1 + $y/100)`.

In your case, you could just write

```
$y = 20;
$x = $y * 1.4 * 1.2;
```

Comment: But how I could for example parse this - (40 + 21%) * (500  -25%) - 25 and so on. Variable count is not limited for now only allowed symbols (+,-,*,/). I would need to split this in smaller equations, right? 1=> 40*1.21 2=>500 * 0.75 3=> 1) * 2) 4=> 3) - 25